# Question regarding OneHotEncoding - Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm working on a project applying the One Hot Encoding technique to a categorical column of a .binetflow file.

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

mydataset = pd.read_csv('originalfiletest.binetflow')

le = LabelEncoder()
dfle = mydataset
dfle.State = le.fit_transform(dfle.State)
X = dfle[['State']].values
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
Onehot = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()

dfle['State'] = Onehot

mydataset.to_csv('newfiletest.binetflow', columns=['Dur','State','TotBytes','average_packet_size','average_bits_psecond'], index=False)
```

[Original binetflow file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBrNR.png)

Currently, I'm using Pandas and I'm being able to apply the technique. The problem is when **I need to write in the second file**.

When I try to write, the output I'm expecting is, for example: 0001 or 0.0.0.1 in variable Onehot, but what I get is either 0.0 or 1.0 when I try to pass it to the column dfle['State'].
The images can be found bellow.

[variable Onehot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ChpU.png)

[column dfle['State']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGMbg.png)

Moreover, the column that should just write, when I write print on the compiler it shows correctly but when it writes in the file it adds a few decimal places.

[Original and new binetflow file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAwHC.png)

Comment: Text information should be part of the question as test, not screencaps, so it is searchable and copyable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onehot is numpy array and the problem is in your assignment of the array to dataframe column

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder

mydataset = pd.DataFrame(data={'State': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd']})

le = LabelEncoder()

mydataset.State = le.fit_transform(mydataset.State)
X = mydataset[['State']].values
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
Onehot = ohe.fit_transform(X).toarray()

dx = pd.DataFrame(data=Onehot)

mydataset['State'] = (dx[dx.columns[0:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(int).astype(str)), axis=1))

mydataset.to_csv('newfiletest.binetflow',
                 columns=['Dur', 'State', 'TotBytes', 'average_packet_size', 'average_bits_psecond'], index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The writing to the second file's working perfectly now. As for the first column not being written correctly, do you have any ideas (image:Original and new binetflow file)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Try to run the edited code above and let me know what the problem is and I will help you further.

Comment: The goal of the code is simply to do the OHE in two columns and write the rest of the columns as they are in the original file. But the column Dur, as shown in the image, is somehow "bugging" when it's written in the second file and passing more content than it should. I didn't want to limit the field because the original file's too large and probably has lines with longer and shorter fields and it could complicate the analysis later. 

https://imgur.com/a/h5RlCWF